# How do I convert a strange integral into a polar integral?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I’m converting integrals into polar integrals, but I don’t understand how to convert, for example, an integral that runs on the upper half of a circle from $-1$ to $2$ on the $x$-axis.

[image]

What’s confusing me is that all the examples I’ve been given have $x$ run from $0$ or $-r$ to $r$.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Which function do you wish to integrate over $\mathcal{D}$? (For its area, the answer is the constant function $1$.) Try proving$$\int_{\mathcal{D}}fdxdy=\left(\int_0^{2\pi/3}\int_0^2+\int_{2\pi/3}^\pi\int_0^{-\sec\theta}\right)rfdrd\theta.$$

Comment: I would try to break up your given region into two pieces - a circular sector, and a right triangle to fill in the left side.

Comment: answer is easily find using $dA = \frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta $ see answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724274/1177689

Answer (score 1):

in polar coordinates:

$$x = rcos\theta$$
$$y = rsin\theta$$

we have that

$$x^2+y^2= r^2$$
$$r^2cos^2\theta+r^2sin^2\theta = r^2$$

$$dA = \frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta$$

$$A = \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta$$
$$A = \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2}(r^2cos^2\theta+r^2sin^2\theta )d\theta$$

because we are integrating tiny triangles with height $d\theta$ and base $r^2$

Comment: Those are not the correct bounds of integration.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  0 and 60 right?